# version conflict updating to 9.4.0

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

**Error**

> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. Please
>   fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   available here) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to
>   9.0.0.

In top level build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha7'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

In app level build gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
```

I have also include

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in the end of the build gradle file.